# Missing template error for specific function – others work fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route that is triggered when someone clicks a hyperlink to download a file.

My routes:

```
'/document/download_some_file/' => 'documents#download_some_file'
```

My controller:

```
def download_some_file
  content = 'hello world'
  send_data content, :filename => 'some_file.dat'
  # if I comment out the above line (send_data) I get a missing template error
  # if I name this function anything other than download_xyz I get a missing template error
end
```

This works fine. However I have another hyperlink:

```
'/document/refresh_files/' => 'documents#refresh_files'
```

then

```
def refresh_files
  #stuff here
  #this throws a missing template error
  #if I rename this to download_xyz it works fine
end
```

So...what's going on here exactly? The first function I showed (download_some_file) does work properly.

The refresh_files is what I'm trying to fix. It should just call another function inside the Documents controller. Even if I just do a `puts` I get a template error.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data), `send_data` is rendering data so Rails does not expect to render a view.  See also Section 12 of [this Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).  Unless you are explicitly rendering like this, Rails will expect a corresponding view for each controller action and render it implicitly.  You can customize what gets rendered as well (see [this Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing with the route. Since you are sending a file in the `download_some_file` method, it does not require a template.

For `refresh_files` I am assuming you are not trying to send a file, but maybe refresh a list. Maybe you want javascript back. This will require a template named `refresh_file.js.erb` that lives in your `app/views/documents` folder. Any format that you are requesting will probably end up needing a template besides maybe json if you send it from the method itself, but you could build a template for that too.

Once you have a template that you want back from the controller in your folder that goes with your method, you will be able to respond to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have corresponding template in view called refresh_files.html.erb Controller method searches template with corresponding name.